# Is this a Javascript blocking / async scenario?

Tags: javascript

The user clicks the map and it calls clickMap, the DIV#calculating is displayed, the map calcs are done and then in updateResults the DIV#calculating is hidden.

However the DIV is never shown on screen.

The console log shows

```
block 9775.199999996403
none 10517.899999998917
```

The delay between show and hide maybe from 100ms up to 5000ms, no matter what I never see the DIV.

```js
function clickMap(e) {
  if (myAStar.nodesPosition[e.offsetY][e.offsetX]) {
    document.getElementById("calculating").style.display = "block";
    console.log(document.getElementById("calculating").style.display, performance.now());
    myAStar = new AStarPathFinder(mapW, mapH);
    path = [];
    myAStar.setStart(0, 0);
    myAStar.setDestination(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
    myAStar.wh = document.getElementById('hWeight').value;
    myAStar.loadMap(map);
    findPath();
    drawMap();
    updateResults();
  } else {
    mapCanvas.classList.add("oops");
    setTimeout(() => {
      mapCanvas.classList.remove("oops");
    }, 500);
  }
}

function updateResults() {
  document.getElementById("calculating").style.display = "none";
  console.log(document.getElementById("calculating").style.display, performance.now());
}
```

Comment: Yes, this issue is caused by the blocking code. Make it asynchronous to allow rendering the box.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks Bergi, I'll get reading on that now I'm sure that's the problem.

Comment: @Bergi Scratching my head on this one, I want it to be synchronous, but the functions are blocking the rendering? The logic and order of everything is ok. A pointer would be appreciated

Comment: You can't have it be synchronous. Just make a small timeout before starting the hard computational work that freezes the UI.